# How to limit Picturebox movement to screen

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, picturebox

I have an application which has a moving Picturebox controlled by a timer whenever a condition is met. All of this works fine. However, I am keen to have the moving Picturebox confine itself within the screen.

My code is here:

public Random r = new Random();

```
private void OutsideBusinessHoursTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int x = r.Next(0, 925);
  int y = r.Next(0, 445);
  this.pbLifebrokerInactive.Top = y;
  this.pbLifebrokerInactive.Left = x;
}
```

How can I best achieve this? Can I do this in the Timer event as well? Thanks for your patience! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but this will confine it to the area of your Form:

```
    private void OutsideBusinessHoursTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = r.Next(0, this.ClientRectangle.Width - this.pbLifebrokerInactive.Width);
        int y = r.Next(0, this.ClientRectangle.Height - this.pbLifebrokerInactive.Height);
        this.pbLifebrokerInactive.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }
```